# Return only odd elements

Tags: matlab, function

This is my first attempt to learn Matlab and I am trying some homework which is evaluated by a p file.  I think my function is correct but I keep getting a negative feedback from the automatic feedback which evaluate the function

> (Feedback: Your function made an error for argument(s) [1 2 3;4 5 6;7
>   8 9])

Problem:

> Write a function called odd_index that takes a matrix, M, as input argument
>   and returns a matrix that contains only those elements of M that are in odd
>   rows and columns. In other words, it would return the elements of M at
>   indices (1,1), (1,3), (1,5), ..., (3,1), (3,3), (3,5), ..., etc.
>   Note that both the row and the column of an element must be odd to be included in the output.
>   The following would not be returned: (1,2), (2,1), (2,2) because either the row or the
>   column or both are even. As an example, if M were a 5-by-8 matrix, then the output must
>   be 3-by-4 because the function omits rows 2 and 4 of M and it also omits columns 2, 4, 6, and 8 of M.

This is the function I wrote:

```
function odd_index
M=[1:5; 6:10; 11:15; 16:20; 21:25];
M=M(1:2:end, 1:2:end);
M
end
```

Any suggestion about what I am doing wrong here will be appreciated.

Comment: This function doesn't appear to take any arguments in - you're setting `M` to the values in your second line every time. Is this the desired behaviour?

Comment: @MattG honestly I am not sure, since the evaluation is done by a p file, I made it in a way that the matrix is generated when I run the function without need of input by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function needs to take in a matrix `M` as an input argument:

```
function M_out = odd_index(M)
    M_out = M(1:2:end, 1:2:end);
end
```

That way, the 'p file' can test it for various inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
function matA=odd_index(matB)
[r,c]=size(matB);
matA=matB(1:2:r,1:2:c);
end
```

Comment: @rayryeng, *and* it uses unnecessary variable definitions.