# I need help to understand the functions of Matlab

Tags: matlab

Can someone explain to me the solution of this exercise:

Exercise

Write a function called odd_index That Takes a matrix, `M`, as input argument and returns a matrix That contains only elements of `M` Those That are in odd rows and columns. In other words, it would return the elements of `M` at indices `(1,1)`, `(1,3)`, `(1,5)`, ..., `(3,1)`, `(3,3)`, `(3,5)` , …, etc. That note both the row and the column of an element must be odd to be included in the output. The following would not be returned: `(1,2)`, `(2,1)`, `(2,2)` Because Either the row or the column or both are even. As an example, if `M` Were a 5-by-8 matrix, the output must be then a 3-by-4 Because the function omits rows 2 and 4 of `M` and it omits Also columns 2, 4, 6, and 8 of `M` .

Solution:

```
 M_out = odd_index function (M)
 M_out = M (1: 2: end, 1: 2: end);
end
```

Link solution: [Return only odd elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739257/return-only-odd-elements/33108952#33108952)

Can someone explain to me how they came to the function `M_out = M (1: 2: end, 1: 2: end) ;.`

Comment: Look at the answer with 10 votes.  That will lead to explain why you need `1:2:end` for both dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function M_out = odd_index (M)
M_out = M(1: 2: end, 1: 2: end);
end
```

I takes each *odd* element of the matrix `M` and returns that to a matrix `M_out`,

```
M = [1 2 3; 4 5 6;7 8 9];
M_out = odd_index(M)

M_out =

     1     3
     7     9
```

where you can see that elements on an odd row *and* on an odd column are being printed, but the elements on even rows and even columns are being left out.

The trick here is to step through the indices in steps of 2 instead of 1. `M(1,1)` gives the element in the upper-left corner of `M`, i.e. 1. `M(1:2,1)` returns the first two elements in the left column: 1 and 4. This happens because `n:m` creates a vector of numbers running from `n` to `m` in steps of 1. You can change this step size by adding a number: `n:x:m`, where `x` specifies how large your steps are. Since the odd numbers are 2 apart, just start your vector at the lowest, positive, odd number, 1, and step with size 2. The last element in your vector `1:2:end` simply means "the end of the vector", thus, if `M = [5x3]` the `end` of the rows is 5, because there are five rows, and the `end` of the columns would be 3, since there are three columns.